# Error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION Very Confused

Tags: error, failing-tests, context, mixed-dml, setup-object

I'm very confused about `MIXED_DML_OPERATION`error. Following test case fails in `production` but passes in `uat`.

```
@IsTest
private class MyControllerTest {
    private static final String USERNAME ='test@systemadmin.com';

    @IsTest
    static void test() {
        ...
    }

    @TestSetup
    static void createMockObjects() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(
                Alias = 'tesAdmin',
                Email = 'test@systemadmin.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LastName = 'Test',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                TimeZoneSidKey='Australia/Sydney',
                ProfileId = p.Id,
                UserName = USERNAME
        );

        insert u;

        String customObjectString = '{"attributes":{"type":"Custom_Object__c"},"Name":"OBJ-01", ...}';
        Custom_Object__c customObj = (Custom_Object__c)JSON.deserialize(customObjectString, Custom_Object__c.class);
        insert customObj;
    }
}
```

Above test class runs perfect in `UAT` environment but fails in `production` with following error.

`MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Custom_Object__c, original object: S2XUserMap: []`

**In many forums it is said that cannot perform DML Operations for setup objects and non-setup objects in the same context. If that is the case, why this runs properly in `UAT`?**

***Note: This happens only after production org is migrated to a different server.***

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this runs properly in UAT.
But you can fix it by using System.runAs()

```
@TestSetup
    static void createMockObjects() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
        User u = new User(
                Alias = 'tesAdmin',
                Email = 'test@systemadmin.com',
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LastName = 'Test',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                TimeZoneSidKey='Australia/Sydney',
                ProfileId = p.Id,
                UserName = USERNAME
        );

        system.runAs(u){
            String customObjectString = '{"attributes":{"type":"Custom_Object__c"},"Name":"OBJ-01", ...}';
            Custom_Object__c customObj = (Custom_Object__c)JSON.deserialize(customObjectString, Custom_Object__c.class);
            insert customObj;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I know, this way I can fix this. I'll update the question with another example. Thank you for your answer anyway!